# Architecture of the page navigation for Xamarin eBook reader

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I develop the Xamarin eBook reader. I want to ask you for an advice about architecture of the page navigation. My application consists of main page which contains a list of books, the page which contains chapters of a specific book, pages which displays a text of the page.

My home page is the custom page which inherits from `ContentPage`.

```
/// <summary>
    /// The home page of the application.
    /// </summary>
    public class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly StackLayout panel;

        /// <summary>
        /// The collection of books.
        /// </summary>
        private IEnumerable<EpubBook> books;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize an instance of the <see cref="MainPage"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="books">The collection of books.</param>
        public MainPage(IEnumerable<EpubBook> books)
        {
            this.Title = "Main page";
            this.books = books;
            this.panel = new StackLayout();

            foreach (EpubBook book in this.books)
            {
                OpenBookButton openBookButton = new OpenBookButton(book)
                {
                    Text = $"Title: {book.Title}"
                };

                openBookButton.Clicked += OnClickOpenBookButton;
                this.panel.Children.Add(openBookButton);
            }

            this.Content = new ScrollView
            {
                Content = this.panel,
                Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical
            };
        }

        private async void OnClickOpenBookButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenBookButton button = (OpenBookButton) sender;
            BookContentPage bookContentPage = new BookContentPage(button.Book.Chapters);
await this.Navigation.PushAsync(bookContentPage);
        }
    }
```

This is my page which displays all chapters of a book.

```
public class BookContentPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly StackLayout panel;

        public BookContentPage(List<EpubChapter> chapters)
        {
            this.Title = "Content page";
            this.panel = new StackLayout();

            foreach (EpubChapter chapter in chapters)
            {
                this.WriteChapter(chapter, panel);
            }

            this.Content = new ScrollView
            {
                Content = panel
            };
        }

        private void WriteChapter(EpubChapter epubChapter, Layout<View> layout)
        {
            // create buttons which have a text which displays the name of the chapter
        }

        private void OnClickOpenBookChapterButton(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {    
            OpenBookChapterButton button = (OpenBookChapterButton) sender;
            BookTextPage bookTextPage = new BookTextPage(button.Chapter);
            this.Navigation.PushAsync(bookTextPage);

            // I want to split bookTextPage to few little screen pages in the future

            this.Navigation.PushAsync(bookTextPage);
        }
    }
```

After all I want to split the book's text to pages and create the `CarouselPage` which will be contains all of these pages. What do you think about my of developing this application? I'm new to `Xamarin.Forms`. Am I on the right way? What I did bad and what should be fixed in my approach?

Comment: Read this article about [Navigation with Xamarin Forms](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/06/01/navigation-with-xamarin-forms.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CarouselPage will soon be deprecated, hence you will want to switch to [CarouselView](https://xamarinhelp.com/carousel-view-xamarin-forms/). Using this control, the page architecture would be fairly easy.

Have one ContentPage for the list of books you have. Then when you click on one, go to another ContentPage, that has a CarouselView inside. This will be bound to the list of pages in your book, that they can then flip through.